# sql query to get exactly the last day result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im looking for a query to gave me the last day result.
the query can be run in any time of day so it shouldnt be hour dependent
and the result must be from starting point of last day and start of today.
i find this , is this give the exact result ?

```
WHERE Date between
select dateadd(d, -2, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
and
select dateadd(d, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: Change this `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` to this `GETDATE()`

Comment: @Justin is should stick with cast one becuase i want from 24 pm of last day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select * from mytable where mydate >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) 
and mydate < convert(date, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem correctly..Add below condition to your select query

```
WHERE Date >=(select dateadd(d, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) AND Date < GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
 select * from tbl
 where dayOfYear(Date)=dayOfYear(dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) and year(Date)=year(getdate())
```